# Complex filtering/subqueries in Django

Tags: django, filter

I have the following models:

```
class CrewMember(models.Model):
    crew = models.ForeignKey(Crew, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="members")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    foreman = models.BooleanField()

class Crew(models.Model):
    crew_type = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Job(models.Model):
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class FieldData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField()
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    crew = models.ForeignKey(Crew, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    data = models.TextField()
```

Essentially, employees on a job can create a field data entry.  Additionally, each Crew of employees, has either one or zero foreman (so `crew.members.filter(foreman=True)` will always return a maximum of one result.

What I need to do is, given a particular `Job` instance, grab all `FieldData` instances that were created by a user that was a foreman in the crew for that day.  E.g., something like this:

```
FieldData.objects.filter(job=some_job, user=<SOMETHING>)
```

where something would be the user that matches:

```
theFieldDataInstance.crew.members.get(foreman=True).user
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the "for that day" part. There seems to be only one `DateField`?

Comment: So on a given day and job, there will be multiple employees on a crew, and up to one foreman.  So what I am trying to retrieve is the foreman's FieldData for each day there was a foreman on a crew, on a job.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a query like

```
first_query=FieldData.objects.filter(job=some_job, crew__foreman=True).user
second_query=FieldData.objects.filter(user=first_query)
#after this if you want user you can just do secondquery.user
```

As the CrewMember has an attribute foreman which is a foreign key to the FeildData class which has an attribute crew, you can split the query in two-part and process it as above.

Comment: user has no field on it named foreman.  The only place where foreman is located is in a crew.  E.g.- crew.members.filter(foreman=True).  So I need to be cross referencing a FieldData's `user` with the user returned by a FieldData's `crew.members.filter(foreman=true).user`

Comment: @MarkD so you want all feild instances, created by a user and who's crew type=foreman with some job right. I corrected my answer. Did I understand the problem correctly?

Comment: Close, however, the filter is more complex.  Crew has members, which can be grabbed via `crew.members`.  Zero or one of those members has `foreman` set to true.   And I have no idea at query time, who the foreman is on the crew attached to a given FieldData.  So I need to filter for any `FieldData` instance (lets call it `fd`) where `fd.user` equals the user returned by `fd.crew.members.filter(foreman=True).user`

Comment: I cannot see any relation between Crew and members. Did you trim your models while posting here?

Comment: So shouldn't there be a foreign key for CrewMembers in Crew?

Comment: DOH!  Sorry, my bad.  Yes, I was trimming much more complex models, and trimmed out the crew foreign key, and added the related_name to the users..  Should be fixed now (CrewMember has `crew = models.ForeignKey(Crew, related_name='members')` now)

Comment: @MarkD I think you want to add the foreign key to the crew right not CrewMembers as Crew has crewMembers

Comment: Nope.  The foreign key should be in CrewMembers, as there are many CrewMembers for a given crew.  Thus why I use "members" as my related_name (so given a Crew, `crew`, I can do `crew.members` to retrieve all employees on a crew.  If the foreign key was in Crew, it could only have a single Crew Member

Comment: So then you would have to change crew attribute in FeildData to 'CrewMember' instead of the 'crew' as otherwise there is no linkage between both the classes.

Comment: @HarshNagarkar- no, it did not.  The structure is OK (now that I fixed the missing relation in my sample code).  All queries, etc, are working just fine on the model, however I was unable to do what I wanted to do in my original question.  I did get around it, by looping, etc..  which worked fine for now.

Comment: Alright, my only suggestion was that you change in FeildData, crew=models.foreignKey(CrewMember),.aA you already have crew variable in CrewMember as foreign key to class Crew. It is good you have found your way. Cheers.